# The continuity of a function at a point $ x = 0$

Tags: calculus, continuity, graphing-functions

Choose correct options , more than one may be correct .

(1)

> $$ \textrm{The function  defined by } \begin{cases} f(x)=\cos\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) & x\neq 0\\ f(0)=0 & \\ \end{cases} \qquad \textrm{is continuous at x=0.} $$

(2)

> $$ \textrm{The function  defined by } \begin{cases} f(x)=\sin x\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) & x\neq 0\\ f(0)=0 & \\ \end{cases} \qquad \textrm{is continuous at x=0.} $$

(3)

> $$ \textrm{The function  defined by } \begin{cases} f(x)=x+\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) & x\neq 0\\ f(0)=1 & \\ \end{cases} \qquad \textrm{is continuous at x=0.} $$

(4)

> $$ \textrm{The function  defined by } \begin{cases} f(x)=x\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) & x\neq 0\\ f(0)=1 & \\ \end{cases} \qquad \textrm{is continuous at x=0.} $$

here is graph of each function  but i don't know how to plot it exactly via wolfram

for (1) : [Graph of function (1) via Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Ccos%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%29%20&dataset=&equal=Submit) 
[image: Graphe of function (1)]

for(2) : [Graph of function (2) via wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csin%20x%5Csin%28%5Cdfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%29)
[image]

for(3) : [Graph of function (3) via wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2b%5Csin%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%29%20)
[image]

for(4) : [Graph of function (4) via wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2b%5Csin%28%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%7D%29%20)
[image]

I think the correct answer is (2) Indeed :

It is well know, that 
$$\left|\sin{x}\right|\leq 1 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Because of this it holds 
$$\left| \sin x \sin\dfrac{1}{x}\right|\leq \left|\sin x\right|\cdot 1 = \left|\sin x\right|$$
Thus
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0 = f(0) $$

which means that $f$ is continous at $x=0$

- Would you please show me why others options aren't correct ?
- How can i plot those functions in wolfram

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Quick:

$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\cos x\,\;or\;\,\sin x\;\;\;\;\;\text{don't exist}$$

and this already takes off options (1) and (3).

In (4) we have a function that goes to zero ($\;x\;$) times a bounded function $\;\left(\sin\frac1x\right)\;$ and thus the limit is zero, yet it doesn't equal the defined value of the function there thus (4) not true.

Comment: Thanks would you please take look to second question

Comment: How can you plot those in WA? I've no idea...but aren't those diagrams in your question from WA??

Comment: yes it's from WA but i can 't add the second term f(0)=0

Comment: The limit exists for (4), so the limit as $x \to 0$ exists for $(\sin x/x) (x \sin(1/x))$. Recheck option (2).

Comment: @nayrb, you rush a little too much to downvote: of course the limit exists in (4): that's *exactly* what I wrote. Yet the limit at zero **and the value of the function at zero** are different and thus the function can't be continuous there.

Comment: Its not continuous for option (4), I agree. I'm saying it is for (2) since if the limit exists for (4), then the limit exists for (2) as well.

Comment: I've no idea what you're talking about, @nayrb. Anyway, why the downvote?

Comment: @DonAntonio, I'm sorry, I'm not being clear. Forget the previous stuff. I think your answer is wrong. Option (2) gives a continuous function since the limit is 0 and the function is defined as 0 at 0.

Comment: @nayrb, that's **exactly** what my answer is saying: the options (1),(3),(4) are off and thus the correct answer is (2) !! Did you read the OP's question **at all** ? He's asking "Would you please show me why others options aren't correct ?", and this is precisely what I did...

Comment: @DonAntonio, I'm really sorry for all the miscommunication and exasperation. No, I didn't read the entire OP carefully but was confused by your answer because you wrote " this already takes off options (1)-(3)", which suggests that option (2) isn't a valid option. At any rate I can't change my downvote unless you edit your answer.

Comment: And if you will, please try not to be so emphatic. I'm not trying to be mean nor am I trying to be a dunce.

Comment: @nayrb, the emphasis comes to point out the unbearable lightness (ala Kundera) with which some people here downvote stuff without *first* taking good care of reading and understanding stuff. As I've found these points don't get you neither girls, fame, money or even chocolate ice cream for free, I'm taking them as an indication *to others* whether an answer *probably* is right or wrong, and this is what your downvote may cause. Nevertheless, and following your point, I've edited my question from "(1)-(3)" to "(1) **and** (3)", to be even clearer.